# Study the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{6n-5}{n^3+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Study the convergence of the following series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{6n-5}{n^3+1}$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{6n-5}{n^3+1}$$

Using L'Hopital rule:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{6n-5}{n^3+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{6}{3n^2} = \frac{6}{\infty} = 0$$

I know that this series tends to $0$. After that, I don't know how to prove whether the series converges or diverges. I tried comparing it to a geometric series, but couldn't find the $r$. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You are incorrect in saying that the "serie tends to $0$". Hint: When you compared leading terms, you found that it "looked like" $\frac{1}{n^2}$. Can you use that to set up a comparison and discuss your attempt?

Comment: @OnceUponACrinoid Actually they are correct, they just checked that the terms of the sequence tend to $0$, which is necessary for the series to be convergent. The real issue is the use of the word "series" for two difference things: the sequence and the series.

Comment: Hint:  Split the numerator of the fractions as $\frac{6n}{n^3+1}-
\frac{5}{n^3+1}$, then use the comparison test for each one of these.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes a lot of sense. I tried comparing it with $\frac{6n-5}{n^3}$, but it was obviously not any help. It makes sense to compare it to $\frac{6}{n^2}$. Thanks guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the comparison test against $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$, which we know converges to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. Note that $\frac{6n-5}{n^3+1} < \frac{6}{n^2}$ for all $n≥1$. By the comparison test, that means that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{6n-5}{n^3+1} < 6\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ and therefore the sum converges.

Comment: Note that knowing that $\zeta(2)=\frac {\pi^2}{6}$ is not needed at all, all that's needed is knowing that it converges.

Answer (score 7):

**HINT:**

$$\frac{6n-5}{n^3+1}\le \frac{6}{n^2}$$